# Расположение картинок на странице

Tags: joomla, html, изображения, css, разметка

Доброе время суток. Имеется картинка jpg (взята из google maps), на ней 5 меток. По причине того, что нужно сделать картинки с метками - ссылки, картинка была разрезана на 20шт.
Все было сделано по причине того, что эта большая картинка должна располагаться в модуле joomla. но при добавлении новой картинки в модуле вверху остается большой пробел. Как можно решить эту проблему?

[image: Разрезка]
[image: Добавление картинок]

Comment: Средствами CSS. Дайте ссылку на сайт для более точного ответа.

Comment: @co11ter, http://saratov-cson.ru  эм... я конечно могу ошибаться, но css в joomla редакторе можно редактировать html код.

Comment: @Ыукпун дал вам совершенно правильный ответ. Выключите редактор и вставьте картинки так, как бы вы их вставили в обычный html код(без отступов).
P.S. Отображение картинок в редакторе joomla может не соответствовать тому, как они будут отображаться на фронтенде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эх вы горе верстальщики используйте тег <map> и не надо резать картинку

Comment: Спасибо! не приходилось таким заниматься((

Comment: Используйте Dreamweaver для удобства, чтоб расчертить области. Очень удобно.

Answer (score 1):

1. нажать кнопку включить редактор
2. ручками там прописать страницу. таблицу или дивы. там обнулить отступы

Answer (score 0):

У вас блок с картой `<div class="moduletable">` вставляется в блок `<div class="user1">`.

user1 в свою очередь имеет ширину заданную стилями в 250рх.

В такую ширину ваша карта не помещается и картинки начинают "падать" одна под другую.